# Combinatorics:Find the integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ k^2 = a {k \choose 2} + b {k \choose 1}$

Tags: combinatorics

For the question

> The objective is to derive a formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2$. Find the integers $a$ and $b$ such that $$ k^2 = a {k \choose 2} + b {k \choose 1}$$

The closest I can come to figuring it out is that $k^2$ can be rewritten as
$$ k \cdot k = a {k \choose 2} b {k \choose 1}$$
Since $k \choose 1$ equals k, we can write
$$ k \cdot k = a {k \choose 2} b \cdot k$$
Then we can say
$$k = a {k \choose 2}$$ and $$k = b {k \choose 1}$$
Then $b \cdot k = k$, so $b = 1$

I am stuck at $a {k \choose 2}=k$. I did try solving for $a$ with
$$ a \bigg ( \frac{k!}{2! (k-2)!} \bigg ) = k$$
$$ a = \frac {2}{k-1}$$ But this is wrong because $a$ is not an integer.

So I thought maybe the way to solve this problem is to use Pascal's triangle and look at the second row (because of $k^2$), which would mean $a = 1$ and $b =2$, but doesn't lead to the LHS equaling the RHS.

I don't know what I am not understanding about the binomial theorem to be able to solve this. Appreciate any tips.

Comment: I think you misread the question. There are numbers $a,b$ such that $k^2=a\binom k2+b\binom k1$. But multiplying instead of adding won't work.

Comment: That's how the question is worded in the book

Comment: So what is "worded" about $k$ then?

Comment: Updated with details about $k$

Comment: No, nothing updated about $k$. The reference is just  $$1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$  The question is, for which $k$ do we solve **your equation**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a typo in the question and you are really asked:

> The objective is to derive a formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2$. Find the integers $a$ and $b$ such that $$ k^2 = a {k \choose 2}+ b {k \choose 1}$$

The point is that we can then write 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2=a\sum_{k=1}^n{k \choose 2}+b\sum_{k=1}^n{k \choose 1}$$

If we plug in ${k \choose 2}=\frac 12k(k-1), {k \choose 1}=k$ we find $a=2, b=1$.  See if that fits into the rest of the proof.

Comment: you're right, i missed the $+$. i updated the original question

Answer (score 0):

I got the equation$$ab=\frac{2}{k-1}$$ I have found $13$ Solutions.

Comment: Me too. But what is the question?